# Openfire not going into setup and showing the admin login page

Tags: installation, openfire

I installed openfire and I am trying to rerun the set up to update domain name information .My setup is working fine for the moment,I just need my server to use a new resolvable domain name that I recently got.

What I am doing:

1.stop the server ( ./openfire stop)
2.Go to the conf dir and change the "true" entry to "false"
3.Restart the server
4.Open my browser and visit :my_domain:9090

After these steps I am presented with the admin login page and when I enter my user name and password I can still get in .Only this time my clients can't login:they get a socket error .When I change the property back to true my users can get in no problem.

After inspection of my mysql database ,I found a table ofProperty that contains the properties used by my server.I backed up the contents of that table and deleted everything in there.Set the property in openfire.xml back to false and restarted the server.The admin login page was still showing up upon visiting my_domain:9090.

I am puzzled here.All the documentation and search entries suggest these steps.My server is ubuntu 14.04 .Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it running,
After some tinkering ,I found that after shutting down openfire and receiving a message that it had successfuly stopped ,the admin page of my openfire installation was still browsable at myDomain:9090 ,even with openfire SHUT DOWN!

I went to my terminal and issued

```
netstat -l
```

to show open listening ports on my server and BAANG!All admin ports of openfire were opened and
listening.I needed to find the program behind those ports and I issued:

```
netstat -l -p
```

to get :

```
Proto  Recv_Q  Send-Q Local Address       Foreign Address      State      PID/Program name

tcp      0       0     33.33.33.33:9090          *:*            LISTEN        878778/program
```

It was the program with the pid of 878778 that was responsible for keeping those ports being
open .I had to kill it.I issued the command:

```
kill -9 878778
```

and the process was gone.And my server wasn't listening on 9090 and 9091 anymore. I browsed myDomain:9090 to make sure it is failing and the page wasn't being found.So far so good.

I restarted openfire

```
./openfire start
```

and typing myDomain:9090 in the browser I could see my long awaited setup page.

Hope this saves somebody some time.